# How can I declare a matrix in Polymer?

Tags: polymer

I gotta pass this as parameter in a polymer element:

```
[
  ["id", "nome",     "idade"],
  [1,    "matheus",  16],
  [2,    "cristian", 16],
  [3,    "pedro",    10],
  [4,    "henrique", 10]
]
```

how can I declare this variable (a matrix) in the polymer propertie field?

How I declare my element:

```
<script>
        Polymer({
            is: "table-element",
            properties: {
                id: String,
                matrixdata: Array
            },

            ready: function() {
               document.getElementById(this.id).appendChild(criarTabela(this.matrixdata));
            }
        });


    </script>
```

Comment: Have you tried passing matrix data directly instead of `this.matrixdata`. Have you tried `console.debug(this.matrixdata)` in `ready`?

Comment: The matrix data's been passing correctly. I mean, I checked and the data's been passing correctly.
I noticed that when I put the 'array' type, I got the blank page

Comment: ... when you add it directly to the code as suggested? What about my 2nd question?

Comment: No, this way: this.matrixdata. About your 2nd question, nothing happened when I added that line... =/

Answer (score 1):

I think this should work

```
<my-comp matrix='[
  ["id", "nome",     "idade"],
  [1,    "matheus",  16],
  [2,    "cristian", 16],
  [3,    "pedro",    10],
  [4,    "henrique", 10]
]'></my-comp>
```

if the type of the `matrix` property is `Array`

```
matrix: {
  type: Array
}
```

See also the `rows` or `data` example in https://elements.polymer-project.org/elements/google-chart

Comment: The outer quotes should be single quotes. `matrix='[ ... `

Comment: Thanks a lot for the hint @Maria :)

Comment: Did not work is not very helpful. Some error? Did something else land in the property? Are you sure you're using it right?

Comment: I'm sorry.
I got a blank page.Nothing happened. I think that's because of the 'array' type

Comment: Check the code examples in the link above, also the source of the google-chart component.